# What is the Zygote copy-on-write heap?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, heap-memory

The [Android memory documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) describes the Zygote heap option (when viewing allocations) on the Android Studio profiler as:

> The copy-on-write heap where an app process is forked from in the Android system

I understand how processes are forked from Zygote and that framework classes are stored and shared here, but I'm not clear what this actually means - What is being copied?

Does this simply mean that when a class is changed or loaded in this area it does copy-on-write in the same way you can implement a collection in Java, or is this something to do with the forking process?

Comment: All "Zygote-based" processes have memory pages that are identical among them. Those pages are not copied, instead everything is linked to the same memory page. If one process writes new data into such a page the page is automatically copied before the write takes place (because otherwise the memory of all forks would be changed) -> copy-on-write

Comment: Ok, very concise! - but you should put it as an answer i can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All "Zygote-based" processes have memory pages that are identical among them.

Those pages are not copied, instead everything is linked to the same memory page. This reduces the amount on RAM used by all the "Zygote-based" processes.

If one of those process writes new data into such a page the page is automatically copied before the write actually takes place (because otherwise the memory of all forks would be changed).

This mechanism is called **copy-on-write**.